# Better way for SQL LEFT JOIN OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've done some searching without success and I want to know if there is some better way to rewrite sql query because this `OR` condition in the `LEFT JOIN` kills the performance:(

For e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM computers
LEFT JOIN monitors ON computers.brand = monitors.brand
LEFT JOIN keyboards ON computers.type = keyboards.type
LEFT JOIN accessories ON accessories.id = keyboards.id OR accessories.id = monitors.id
GROUP BY computers.id
ORDER BY computers.id DESC
```

Sorry for dumb question, but is it possible to rewrite `OR` statement to improve performance?

Comment: i think you have an issue with your database... normally you will have PARTS table for all the accessories and MODEL for the model name which relates to your parts

Comment: Model i.e. iMac and branding... then Parts will be (CPU, Keyboard, LED etc)

Comment: **distinct** PLUS **group by** is the most likely cause of the poor performance and/or lack of indexes

Comment: Sorry, but It is just an example here. Names have no meaning, only params relation. Thank you for taking some time for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it will make any difference, but you could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN monitors ON computers.brand = monitors.brand
LEFT JOIN keyboards ON computers.type = keyboards.type
LEFT JOIN accessories ON a1.id IN (keyboards.id, monitors.id)
GROUP BY computers.id
ORDER BY computers.id DESC
```

You could also join to the same table twice, if you are comfortable having two sets of accessories columns (perhaps using `coalesce()` a bunch in the `SELECT` list):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM computers
LEFT JOIN monitors ON computers.brand = monitors.brand
LEFT JOIN keyboards ON computers.type = keyboards.type
LEFT JOIN accessories a1 ON a1.id = keyboards.id 
LEFT JOIN accessories a2 ON a2.id = monitors.id
GROUP BY computers.id
ORDER BY computers.id DESC
```

And, fwiw, this query would not be legal in most modern database engines. If you want to `GROUP BY` a field, the ANSI SQL standard says you can't also just put `*` (even with `DISTINCT`) in the `SELECT` list, because you haven't specified which values to keep and which to discard as the database rolls up the group... the results are undefined, and that's a bad thing.

Comment: same as below.. OR and IN are just the same on this regard. but you are not solving the problem here

Comment: It is logicially the same, but it's usually worth trying... sometimes the query optimizer can surprise you.

Comment: the 2nd solution is appropriate.. but the 1st one won't make any improvements

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I Agree with you.

Comment: Logically the same but not for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `SELECT DISTINCT *`, so its checking that your entire record is unique across all rows it gets, which is 3 tables worth. Its probably going to be already unique, if your primary keys and unique indexes are set up correctly its definitely unique, so just take it out.

If your primary keys and indexes arent setup, do that first. Primary key on fields named id.

That and `SELECT *` incurs a big overhead since it has to figure out what the rest of your columns are.

Guessing without knowing what the table structure actually is: Since you are grouping by `GROUP BY computers.id`, put that in your `SELECT` instead and take it out of your `GROUP BY`.

`SELECT DISTINCT computers.id`